# Can not compile the MVWAP indicator

Tags: pine-script

Here is the code I am using :

```
/// MVWAP ///
avlength = input(title="MVWAP Length", type=int, defval=21)
av = ema(vwap,avlength)
plotav = plot(av,color=color.fuchsia, transp=0, title = "MVWAP")
mvwap = av
```

And the error I am getting:

> Processing script... line 17: Undeclared identifier 'int'; line 18: Undeclared identifier 'avlength'; line 19: Undeclared identifier 'av'; line 20: Undeclared identifier 'av'

Answer (score 1):

Two minutes with Google showed me that it needs to be:

```
avlength = input(title="MVWAP Length", type=input.int, defval=21)
```